# Homework - TICTACTOE - addressing issue

Tags: assembly, mips

1. Hey guys I am having a problem understanding the behavior of my program. I am trying to store an address to return to, but it keeps being overwritten somehow. This is homework so don't give me an easy answers! Perhaps just an explantion as to how `jal` might be overwriting my `$s0` register. I don't quite understand how it possible. I put comments in the code so you can see where the loop is occuring.

2.

```
.data                               # data segment for variables and strings

# These are all the strings that will need to be outputted to the console

title: .asciiz "Tic-Tac-Toe!\n\n"
oprompt: .asciiz "O player: Please enter row/col, one per line:\n\n"
xprompt: .asciiz "X player: Please enter row/col, one per line:\n\n"
invposstr: .asciiz " is an invalid position. Try again.\n\n"
owinstr: .asciiz "O  won  the  game,\n\n  exiting. . ."
xwinstr: .asciiz "X  won  the  game,\n\n  exiting. . ."
catstr: .asciiz "CAT  game,\n\n  exiting. . ."
border: .asciiz "\n\n _ _ _ \n"

# Initialze the board with 9 bytes

board: .byte 'X','X','X','X','X','_','X','_','_' 

.text                       # text segment for instructions

main:                       # begin the main func

li $v0, 4               #set v0 to print string
la $a0, title               #set string to print (in $a0) as title
syscall                 #execute

li $s1, 0               #use s1 as the game counter (up to 9 turns)


playerx:                #player x will always go first

li $v0, 4               #prepare to print string
la $a0, xprompt         #load the get move prompt
syscall

jal get_valid_move          #go get a valid move address

# I am having trouble returning here

li $t0, 'X'             #load asciiz code for X
sb $t0, ($v0)               #store the X into the board address

addi $s1, 1             #increment the game counter to next turn

jal print_board         #after getting the move, print the board status

# And here  

playero:                #player o will always go second

li $v0, 4               #prepare to print string
la $a0, oprompt             #load the get move prompt
syscall

jal get_valid_move          #go get a valid move address    

# And here

li $t0, 'O'             #load asciiz code for O
sb $t0, ($v0)               #store the O into the board address

addi $s1, 1             #increment the game counter to next turn

jal print_board         #after getting the move, print the board status

# And here

j playerx               #go back to player x turn


# I store the current return address below (first time) 

print_board:                #function to print the status of the board

move $s0, $ra           #save the recent return address

la $t1, board           #load the board address

li $v0, 4           #set v0 to print string
la $a0, border          #set string to print (in $a0) as prompt
syscall             #execute

li $t0, 0           #use as counter for loop


loop:               #use loop to print 1 row at a time

    li $v0, 11      #prepare to print char
    li $a0, 124     #asciiz code for |
    syscall

    lb $a0, ($t1)       #load next byte from board
    li $v0, 11          #prepare to print char
    syscall

    addi $t1, $t1, 1        #increment address of board to next byte/char
    addi $t0, $t0, 1        #increment loop counter

    beq $t0, 3, rowend      #go print special stuff at end of row
    beq $t0, 6, rowend      #go print special stuff at end of row
    beq $t0, 9, rowend      #go print special stuff at end of row

    j loop              #go back to top

rowend:

    li $a0, 124         #asciiz for |
    li $v0, 11          #prepare to print char
    syscall

    li $a0, 10          #ascizz for newline
    li $v0, 11          #prepare to print char
    syscall

    blt $t0, 9, loop        #unless at the last row, loop

    li $a0, 10          #ascizz for newline
    li $v0, 11          #prepare to print char
    syscall

    jr $ra              #return to the gameplay in main


entry_address:                  #function to transform user input (row, col) into board address

move $t0, $a1                   #make a copy of row for use
move $t1, $a2               #make a copy of col for use     
addi $t0, $t0, -1           #use n-1 for accessing storage address
addi $t1, $t1, -1           #use n-1
mul $t0, $t0, 3             #mul the row by 3
la $v0, board               #load base address of the board
add $v0, $v0, $t0           #add the row offset
add $v0, $v0, $t1           #add the col offset
                #v0 now holds the correct board position address

jr $ra                  #now go back to check if valid move


valid_position:

li $v0, 1           #assume valid
blt $a1, 1, inv         #if row is less than 1
bgt $a1, 3, inv         # or if row is greater than 3
blt $a2, 1, inv         # or if col is less than 1
bgt $a2, 3, inv         # or if col is greater than 3 change validity

jr $ra              #go back to get_valid_move at last instruction

inv:
li $v0, 0           #since branched, change to inv
jr $ra              #go back to get_valid_move at last instruction


# I store the current return address into s0 below (the 2nd time)

get_valid_move:

move $s0, $ra           #save the recent return address

li $v0, 5           #prepare to read row int
syscall
move $a1, $v0           #copy the read int into argument to be passed
li $v0, 5           #prepare to read col int
syscall
move $a2, $v0           #copy the read int into argument to be passed

jal valid_position      #go make sure pos is valid
beq $v0, 0, invalid     #go tell user if valid_position returned false 

jal entry_address       #position was good so go get entry_address

# THE JR STATEMENT BELOW IS LOOPING BACK HERE
# I need to return to the last instruction in main which I thought I stored in $s0

li $t0, '_'         #use underscore for comparison
lb $t1, ($v0)           #load the byte from the entry_address
bne $t0, $t1, invalid           #if entry is taken, get another move

jr $s0              #since move was valid go back to gameplay in main

invalid:

    li $v0, 1       #prepare to print int
    move $a0, $a1       #load row numb
    syscall
    li $v0, 11      #prepare to print char
    li $a0, 44      #load comma asciiz
    syscall
    li $v0, 1       #prepare to print int
    move $a0, $a2       #load col numb
    syscall
    li $v0, 4       #prepare to print string
    la $a0, invposstr   #load invalid pos message
    syscall

    j get_valid_move    #repeat the user input loop


check_all_match:
print_winner_and_exit:
row_winner:
col_winner:
diag_winner:
check_for_win:

# After printing all the results, we can exit the program
exit:

li $v0, 10              # set v0 to exit
syscall                 # execute exit
```

Comment: I have a feeling I need to start implementing a stack for my return addresses. Otherwise maybe an easier solution would be to attach labels up in main so I can simply jump to them directly when I need to. 

Which solution would be more efficient/correct?

Comment: A stack is more flexible, and can be used the same way everywhere.  If you ever want to use actual subroutines, that would be the way to go.  But if you know where every jump goes, it is flexibility you don't need.

Comment: I have implemented a stack. My code seems to run in single step mode exactly as intended. However in a full run I am getting stuck in that same loop. How is that even possible?

Comment: Nevermind! I wasn't popping the stack after restoring the return address! Gosh it is always the smallest of things.